# make an abosolute position div stretch content width

Tags: css, position, css-position

hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a div that is absolutly positioned (this can not be changed). This div has a maximum and minimum width.

Want i want to achieve is that the div stretch to its content and only when it overpases the width, start with a new line.

HTML:

```
<div class="black_tooltip_container ">
    some text in here, it can be anything!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
position:absolute; min-width:10px; max-width:150px;
```

What i see:

```
 _____________
  | some      |
  | text      |
  | in        |
  | here,     |
  | it        |
  | can       |
  | be        |
  | anything! |
  _____________
```

What i want to see:

```
          width: 150px
  _______________________________
  | some text   in here, it can |
  | be anything!                |
  ______________________________
```

**EDIT:**
Issue solved. The problem was that I didn't realize the div was nested very far away in a div that was with relative position and width:50px;

After removing it from it's parent, it worked as spected

Comment: it's working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/dV2Bm/

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work:

```
<div class="black_tooltip_container ">
    some text in here, it can be anything!
</div>

.black_tooltip_container {
    border:1px solid;
    min-width:10px; 
    max-width:150px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**See it here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nbHMY/

Comment: Fixed the fiddle url.